# jQuery not working in firefox and internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, addclass

Alright, I have jQUery function which adds class to a `div#float` once `div#floatLunch` gets to the top of the page. It works fine in chrome, but doesn't work at all in mozila and IE.
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JKA7j/1/

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var targetDiv = $('#float');
    var matchHeight = $('#floatLunch').position().top;
    if ($(document.body).scrollTop() >= matchHeight) {
        // this is where you're css amendments would be done
        if (!targetDiv.hasClass('fixedPos')) {
            targetDiv.addClass('fixedPos');
        }
    } else {
        if (targetDiv.hasClass('fixedPos')) {
            targetDiv.removeClass('fixedPos');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Is there a fix to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(document.body).scrollTop()
```

to:

```
$(document).scrollTop()
```

Also, you can move the `matchHeight` and `targetDiv` declarations and place them outside the scroll event, no need to put extra load on the script just to find the same result every time:

```
var targetDiv = $('#float'),
    matchHeight = $('#floatLunch').position().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    targetDiv.toggleClass('fixedPos', $(document).scrollTop() >= matchHeight);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JKA7j/3/

Answer (score 3):

Change out: `$(document.body)` for `$(this)` which is the same as `$(window)`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JKA7j/7/ (tested to work with Chrome 15, IE 8, Firefox 8, Opera 11).

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code: http://jsfiddle.net/JKA7j/4/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var targetDiv = $('#float');
    var matchHeight = $('#floatLunch').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= matchHeight) {
        // this is where you're css amendments would be done
        if (!targetDiv.hasClass('fixedPos')) {
            targetDiv.addClass('fixedPos');
        }
    } else {
        if (targetDiv.hasClass('fixedPos')) {
            targetDiv.removeClass('fixedPos');
        }
    }
});
```